# Can I create an SQL query that joins two tables where one has key value pairs?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables (in Woo Commerce in WordPress) where I would like to merge the results

A simplified version of the tables are:

| ID | Product title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Gadget |
| 2 | Gizmo |

And

| Meta_ID | Product_ID | Meta_key | Meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | stock | 20 |
| 2 | 1 | download | No |
| 3 | 2 | stock | 12 |
| 4 | 2 | download | yes |

'ID' in the first table corresponds to the foreign key of 'Product_ID' in the second table.

Is there any way I can use a select query to merge these to produce the following result:

| ID | Product_title | stock | download |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Gadget | 20 | No |
| 2 | Gizmo | 12 | Yes |

Comment: You're asking how to *Pivot* your data

Comment: Join 2 table colies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

The answer without pivot:

```
SELECT
    id,
    product_title,
    b.meta_value AS 'stock',
    c.meta_value AS 'download' 
FROM
    table1 AS a
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON (a.id = b.product_id AND b.meta_key = 'stock' )
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS c ON (a.id = c.product_id AND c.meta_key = 'download')
```